# How can I set up a splash page that is redirected to only one time for the visitor?

Tags: redirect, cookies

I would like every new visitor to be redirected to a splash page upon their first visit. They need to enter their email/submit in order to get into the site. This isn't the standard login type of arrangement, I don't want them to have to log in or hit this splash page again the next time they come back to the site.

Does that make sense?

Assume I know nothing - you'll be close to right....so as clear/instructive as possible.

Comment: Use cookies (http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) or if the user has any information saved into wordpress, use user meta functions to store the information once the splash page has been seen, and retrieve it back once the user access the page again. (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta)

Comment: This question shows no real effort and is just asking "Hey, do this task for me!" Cookies is the right direction, have you tried creating a cookie yet?

Comment: Howdy_McGee - I wasn't asking for someone to do it for me - I was asking for guidance. Not meaning to be disrespectful - but I didn't know where to begin, if it was possible...nothing.

Comment: Using post meta will be a better option then using cookies. For example. You can check for a postmeta `show_splash` if it exists. When it does show the splash page.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a splash page adds an extra step between your user and the information they are looking for. Making it non-optional as you seem to be suggesting will have a serious impact upon your visitor figures. Personally I would not want to impart my email address to a website without knowing more about the site and if it even has the relevant information I am looking for. I would strongly suggest you make this an optional pop-up.

Now to answer your question. To achieve this you would need a plugin, you can either [write your own](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) or use a [pre-built one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=pop-up%20form). I personally would write my own as I could tailor it to my own needs.

As others have suggested [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) are the best way to achieve this. If you do use cookies you will need to display a [warning message](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-pecr/cookies-and-similar-technologies/) to visitors from the EU that you are storing a cookie on their computer.

Comment: I just realised that the original link I provided about the cookie warnings was not actually a government agency website but a private company. I've amended the link to go to a government agency. In my defense the ICO website isn't properly indexed.